# Customize the login form component in the lightning community

Tags: community

I need to customize the login form (and register) of my lightning community to modify the messages when the user fails his authentication or his registering.

Is there a way to do that without developing a new component?

I read the documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5) but I can't see the standard login form component in the lightning components menu in the setup but I cam see my custom lightnings components, do you know why please?

Aurélien[image]